# Unable to maintain one to many relationship in Eloquent using laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I am using laravel eloquent model so there are three tables tempsocials, tempusers and tempdevices. so one user can have multiple devices and multiple social acounts.
I created a models for three of above table and trying to maintain relationship in between like following

**This is my Tempuser model:**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tempuser extends Model
{
    public function tempsocials(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Tempsocial');
    }

    public function tempdevices(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Tempdevice');
    }
}
```

**This is my Tempdevice model:**

```
 namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tempdevice extends Model
{
    public function tempusers(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Tempuser');
    }
}
```

**And this one is last Tempsocial model:**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tempsocial extends Model
{
    public function tempusers(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Tempuser');
    }
}
```

**Now this is my controller where i want to retrive all the devices and social accounts of particular user**

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
    use App\Http\Requests;
    use App\tempLogin;
    use App\Tempdevice;
    use App\Tempuser;
    use App\Tempsocial;

    class loginController extends Controller
    {
        public function check_credentials(Request $request){

          $count=0;

          if($request->header('content-type')=='application/json'){


            $temp=new Tempuser;
            $devices = $temp->tempdevices();
            return $devices;

          }
       }
  }
```

But i got following error:

> Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany could
>   not be converted to string

Answer (score 0):

You're making a new `Tempuser()`, it has no id, so your relation returns nothing as expected, you will need to pass an id to the method and with that id you could do something like:

```
Tempuser::find($id);
```

This will then return an actual model instead of creating a new one.

Also because when you call `->tempdevices()` as a function it will return a query builder, instead when you do `->tempdevices` it will return a collection, change it like this:

```
$devices = $temp->tempdevices;
```

Also, if you expect a json response (if thats not the case you can ignore this part), it might be better to also state it in your return by doing:

```
return response()->json($devices);
```

Comment: I made changes as you suggested but still i have a blank json response.

Comment: then your if statement returns false since that wont give you any return values, what happens if you remove the if statement?

Comment: why i need $request->ajax(). sorry but i don't know about. actually i am a beginner.

Comment: Well your if statement seems to be for checking if the request is ajax right?, `$request->ajax()` does exactly that for you :), but can you try removing the if statement and checking if it returns a json then? (as expected)

Comment: I removed that if condition but still i got a blank json response.

Comment: Is your database properly filled then?, by blank do you mean a white page or something like `{}`?

Comment: That means the function works, your result is just empty, check your database or create testdata that fits what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: ya.. I filled it properly. there is a column tempuser_id in tempdevices table.

Comment: there are already two records present there. so according to me this should give me a one record.

Comment: is there i need to pass id of tempusers table ?

Comment: Ah i see now, you're making a `new Tempuser()`, it has no ID, so your relation returns nothing as expected, check my updated answer.

Comment: but the thing is , requst comes with mobile no.  so i can access mobile no. like $request->mobile . and i want to find out id of user for matching mobile no. . how can i do all this??

Comment: and later how will i pass that id to device table to retrive devices for user.

Comment: It might be a good idea to read the documentation and maybe watch some [laracasts](https://laracasts.com/) to get known with the framework :)